# First MAAS setup, sanity check

Tags: maas

I was given 7 old servers and told to find a use for them or recycle them. I'm trying to get MAAS working.

Management server is a Dell R510 with 2 NICs. I initially thought NIC 1 would go to the company network and NIC 2 would go to an isolated network until I can get everything working. The main network already has provisions in place for PXE booting for other reasons, so I'm not going to be able to interfere with that. Can I still use MAAS to roll out and manage systems?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the MaaS server itself, does not need to be PXE Boot enabled, that would be the nodes that are connected to the private network that would be in PXE Boot.